ARCH-Vasicek model solution
I understand how we can obtain the solution of Vasicek model $dr_t=\alpha(\mu-r_t)dt+\sigma dW_t$:
$$
r_t=r_0e^{-\alpha t}+\mu(1-e^{-\alpha t})+\sigma\int_0^te^{-\alpha(t-s)dW_{s}}
$$
This easily allows me to find $\mathbb{E}[r_t]$ and $Var[r_t]$.
However, I am stuck with following ARCH-Vasicek discrete equations. What I'm trying to do is write the model in continuous form and find its closed-form solution to get the expectation and variance of $r_t$.
$$
\Delta r_t=\alpha(\mu-r_{t-1})dt+\epsilon_t \\
\epsilon_t = \sqrt{\sigma^2_t}u_t, u_t \to iid(0,1)\\
\sigma^2_t=\omega+b_1\epsilon^2_{t-1} 
$$
I'm not very good at stochastic calculus and I suspect there may not be a closed-from solution. Anyway, any help would be appreciated.
